# Message shown when adding a homescreen shortcut.

Tags: android

When creating a homescreen shortcut through my application, I see a dialogue come up on the bottom of the screen that says something like "shortcut .... created", "shortcut .... already exist", or "shortcut ... deleted". Is there a way to disable this dialogue/message?

Comment: duplicate of [Android Disabling message when adding a shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335073/android-disabling-message-when-adding-a-shortcut) by the same user from 22h ago.

Comment: Well, it was closed as not a real question, so given the more detailed wording, I assume the OP is trying to clarify the question to make it a valid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable this dialogue/message?

No, sorry.